# Python HTTPSConnection.close() does not appear to close the connection?

Tags: python, https

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm just doing something wrong.  If I were to do an HTTP connection like this:

```
import httplib

http_connection = httplib.HTTPConnection("192.168.192.196")
http_connection.request("GET", "/")
http_connection.sock.settimeout(20)
response = http_connection.getresponse()
data = response.read()
http_connection.close()
```

Then at a DOS prompt, I do this:

```
netstat -ano | find /i "192.168.192.196:80" | find /i "ESTABLISHED"
```

I get nothing.

However, if I do the same thing, but change it to an HTTPSConnection:

```
import httplib

http_connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection("192.168.192.196")
http_connection.request("GET", "/")
http_connection.sock.settimeout(20)
response = http_connection.getresponse()
data = response.read()
http_connection.close()
```

Then do this:

```
netstat -ano | find /i "192.168.192.196:443" | find /i "ESTABLISHED"
```

I will actually see that the connection remains established until I actually ^Z out of the Python shell.

This is happening in one of the applications I'm responsible for.  Python isn't actually hanging there - it's simply leaving the connection open.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Do I need extra code to close the HTTPS connection?

This is Python 2.6.4, btw.

Comment: When I try this (on Windows XP using Python 2.6.4), I see the connection goes to CLOSE_WAIT and eventually goes away. Is your server doing something odd?

Comment: This is weird. If you delete the connection (`del http_connection`) and run the garbage collector, the connection gets closed. It also works with Python 3.1, maybe because the GC behavior has changed, maybe not...

Comment: Dave Bacher: No, I don't think the server's doing anything weird.  I tried this on a standard HTTPS web server as well and it does the same thing.

AndiDog: Running gc.collect() seems to clear the connection... I'm just not sure what the impact of doing that will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if you send the "Connection: close" HTTP header, this isn't an issue - although I still think that .close() should actually close the connection like it does for HTTPConnection.